# Why does my subprocess.call(command) code write nothing to a txt output file?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use the subprocess module of Python 3 to call a command (i.e. `netstat -ano > output.txt`), but when I run the script, the output file gets created, but nothing gets written into it, in other words, its just blank.

I've tried looking into the subprocess module API about how the `subprocess.call()` method works, and searching Google for a solution. I tried using the `subprocess.check_output()` method, but it printed it out as an unformatted string, rather than the column-like format that entering `netstat -ano` into Windows command prompt usually gives.

This is my current code:

```py
import subprocess as sp

t = open('output.txt', 'w')

command = 'netstat -ano > output.txt'
cmd = command.split(' ')
sp.call(cmd) # sp.call(['netstat', '-ano', '>', 'output.txt'])
t.close()
```

I thought it was maybe because I didn't use the `write()` method. But when I changed my code to be

```py
t.write(sp.call(cmd))
```

I would get the error that the `write()` method expects a string input, but received an int.

I expected the output to give me what I would normally see if I were to open command prompt (in Windows 10) and type `netstat -ano > output.txt`, which would normally generate a file called "output.txt" and have the output of my netstat command.

However when I run that command in my current script, it creates the 'output.txt' file, but there's nothing written in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just cast your `cmd` to a `str` like `t.write(str(cmd))`it will write to output.txt

```
import subprocess as sp

t = open('output.txt', 'w')

command = 'netstat -ano > output.txt'
cmd = command.split(' ')
t.write(str(cmd))
sp.call(cmd) # sp.call(['netstat', '-ano', '>', 'output.txt'])
t.close()
```